# Buttons to Message Box in Visual Studio 2008

Tags: c#, button, custom-controls, messagebox

Is it possible to add custom buttons (or) User defined buttons inside Message Box in Visual Studio Windows Forms application ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a quick guide to [making a custom dialog box](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/154680/A-customizable-NET-WinForms-Message-Box), which is going to be the ideal solution for you in this scenario, in my opinion.

Answer (score 1):

The simple answer is: no it's not.

The long answer is that it's not possible using the managed API but it *may* be possible using the Win32 API. Here's a good tutorial on [using Windows Hooks to customize the operating system message box dialog](http://www.catch22.net/tuts/custom-messagebox).

Answer (score 1):

The .net `MessageBox` class does not offer such functionality. However, the native Win32 API does so through the [`TaskDialog`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb787471.aspx) API. The main advantage of this approach, as opposed to writing a custom dialog, is that you will be using a native system component and so your dialog will feel at home on the platform.

A very simple example of the task dialog looks like this:

[image]

And there is lots of scope for much more complexity, as is explained in the link above.

You'll need to p/invoke to this function. It's one of the more messy functions to call so expect a little work before you have a working solution. You can find some C# code to wrap it up [here](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/TaskDialogforWinForm), but I can't say that I personally have experience of this.